# Topological vector space, and balanced sets.

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Wikipedia states:

> Every topological vector space has a local base of absorbing and
>   balanced sets.

I'm not a big expert in the subject. But I'd like to see the proof of such statement. Any clue?

I've attempted to prove it using the definition of *basis for a topology*, and the continuity of these operations in t.v.s.

Comment: A "local basis (of a point)" is not meant to be a "basis": it is a "fundamental system of open neighbourhoods of $x$" (i.e. a family $\mathcal U$ of open neighbourhoods of $x$ such that for any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there is $V\in\mathcal U$ such that $V\subseteq U$). Wikipedia means a local basis of $0$, there.

Comment: Still, i'd like to see the proof.

Answer (score 5):

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $0$. Since $0*x=0$ and by the continuity of the scalar multiplication, we get $ \delta >0$ such that $tx \in U$ for all $|t| \le \delta$. Hence: $x \in \lambda U$ for $|\lambda| \ge 1/ \delta$. This shows that U is absorbing.

Since $0*0=0$ and by the continuity of the scalar multiplication,we get $ \delta >0$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $tV \subset U$ for $|t| \le \delta$. Hence $ \delta V \subset \lambda U$ for $|\lambda| \ge 1$.

It's your turn to show that $U$ contains a balanced neighborhood of $0$.