# Balancing convex absorbing neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Given a convex absorbing neighborhood of 0 in a topological vector space is it always possible to construct a subset that is also convex absorbing neighborhood of 0 but balanced as well?

A locally convex space is topological vector space with has a neighborhood base of 0 of balanced absorbing convex sets.
The questions corresponds to the question if it is possible to drop the requirement of being balanced.

For topological vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ that should be indeed the case (take $-V \cap V$ if $V$ is the convex absorbing neighborhood) but what about spaces over $\mathbb{C}$?

(E.g. here the construction of balanced absorbing sets in arbitrary vector spaces is shown: 
[Topological vector space, and balanced sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411024/topological-vector-space-and-balanced-sets%E2%80%9E))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We’ll use [Functional Analysis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c33c/2a204591f068b2f8e0bb85239f6ed99ee978.pdf) by Huiqiang Jiang for references. Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $U$ be a convex neighborhood of $0$ in $X$. Then $U$ is absorbing, see the last sentence at p.3.  By Remark 1, $U$ contains a balanced
convex neighborhood of $0$. This follows from the construction from the proof of Theorem 3. Since scalar multiplication is continuous, exists $\delta > 0$, and an open neighborhood $V$ of the zero such that $\alpha V \subset U$ whenever $|\alpha| <\delta$. Then $W=\bigcup_{|\alpha|<\delta} \alpha V$ is balanced and $W\subset U$. The convex hull of $W$ is a convex balanced absorbing neighborhood of $0$ contained in $U$.

Comment: Great, that looks really good! Thanks a lot Alex!